# Core Plot 1.4 Scatter Plot only displaying first tick with data

Tags: ios7, core-plot

I'm experiencing some unexpected results with the Scatter Plot since I've started using Core Plot 1.4.  I've been using an older version of Core Plot and have recently upgraded to 1.4.  Since upgrading to this release my Scatter Plot isn't rendering correctly.  It only seems to be rendering the first x axis tick mark.  I've tried several different things to no luck.  It is probably a new setting in 1.4 that I'm missing. Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be happening to cause this?  I have a sample project that I've created and can post to Github if anyone wants to try to recreate this behavior.

**I've attached Screenshots**:

*Older version of Core Plot*

[image: Older version of Core-Plot]

*Core Plot 1.4*

[image: Newer version of Core-Plot]

**Here is some sample code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.hostView = [(CPTGraphHostingView *) [CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.hostView.allowPinchScaling = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.hostView];


// 1 - Create the graph
CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.hostView.bounds];
//[graph applyTheme:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];
self.hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
// 2 - Set graph title
NSString *title = @"Portfolio Prices: April 2012";
graph.title = title;
// 3 - Create and set text style
CPTMutableTextStyle *titleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
titleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
titleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
titleStyle.fontSize = 16.0f;
graph.titleTextStyle = titleStyle;
graph.titlePlotAreaFrameAnchor = CPTRectAnchorTop;
graph.titleDisplacement = CGPointMake(0.0f, 10.0f);
// 4 - Set padding for plot area
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingLeft:40.0f];
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingRight:30.0f];
[graph.plotAreaFrame setPaddingBottom:30.0f];
// 5 - Enable user interactions for plot space
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
//plotSpace.delegate = self;

NSArray  *dataTimes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"12am", @"1am", @"2am", @"3am", @"4am", @"5am", @"6am", @"7am", @"8am", @"9am", @"10am", @"11am", @"12pm", @"1pm", @"2pm", @"3pm", @"4pm", @"5pm", @"6pm", @"7pm", @"8pm", @"9pm", @"10pm", @"11pm",nil];


// 1 - Create styles
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 12.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
axisTextStyle.fontSize = 11.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
CPTMutableLineStyle *gridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;
// 2 - Get axis set
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
// 3 - Configure x-axis
CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.title = @"Time of Day";
x.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
x.titleOffset = 15.0f;
x.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
x.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
x.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
x.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
x.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
//CGFloat dateCount = [[[CPDStockPriceStore sharedInstance] datesInMonth] count];
NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dataTimes];
NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:dataTimes];
NSInteger i = 0;
for (NSString *time in dataTimes) {
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:time  textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    CGFloat location = i++;
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
    label.offset = x.majorTickLength;
    if (label) {
        [xLabels addObject:label];
        [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
    }
}
x.axisLabels = xLabels;
x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;

// 4 - Configure y-axis
CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.title = @"Price";
y.titleTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
y.titleOffset = -40.0f;
y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
y.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
y.labelOffset = 16.0f;
y.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
y.majorTickLength = 4.0f;
y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
NSInteger majorIncrement = 100;
NSInteger minorIncrement = 50;
CGFloat yMax = 700.0f;  // should determine dynamically based on max price
NSMutableSet *yLabels = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMajorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *yMinorLocations = [NSMutableSet set];
for (NSInteger j = minorIncrement; j <= yMax; j += minorIncrement) {
    NSUInteger mod = j % majorIncrement;
    if (mod == 0) {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", j] textStyle:y.labelTextStyle];
        NSDecimal location = CPTDecimalFromInteger(j);
        label.tickLocation = location;
        label.offset = -y.majorTickLength - y.labelOffset;
        if (label) {
            [yLabels addObject:label];
        }
        [yMajorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:location]];
    } else {
        [yMinorLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInteger(j)]];
    }
}
y.axisLabels = yLabels;    
y.majorTickLocations = yMajorLocations;
y.minorTickLocations = yMinorLocations;

}
```

Comment: The plot space delegate behavior changed in 1.4, but you already commented that out.

Comment: The 1.4 release notes states that it added new delegate methods for axis labels. Could this have anything to do with it? Or do you think that it is a plot space issue?

Comment: Starting with release 1.4, the `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:` delegate method is called any time a plot range changes, not just when scrolling and zooming.